# Warning: chmod(): Can not call chmod() for a non-standard stream

Tags: php

I am trying to change file permission to 0777 in php but I get this error: 
`Warning: chmod(): Can not call chmod() for a non-standard stream`
I tried with `chmod` but doesn't work.

```
$imagethumb = 'http://'.$root.'/scrapers/thumbnails/'.$copiedimage;
    //looks like http://domain.com/scrapers/thumbnails/image.jpeg
chmod($imagethumb, 0777);
```

Please let me know where I am mistaking.

Comment: Is the file on the same system as your php? I don't think you can change permissions on a file via http link.

Comment: Just `'/scrapers/thumbnails/'.$copiedimage`

Comment: You can't chmod a URL.  You need to use a path to a file on your filesystem.

Comment: Its expected to use chmod for local files using local path not web address. if that file on your server then you can use `chmod($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/scrapers/thumbnails/image.jpeg', 0777);`

Comment: @Sam: It should probably be an absolute path: `/var/www/scrapers/thumbnails/...`

Comment: I see now. So it needs an absolute path. Thanks all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well since no one seems to want to ANSWER the question, rather to comment the answer, here's my answer:

You cannot chmod a URL as there would be no security in that. In order to fix your code, you should use a constant like $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. Here's an example of what you can do.

```
chmod($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/scrapers/thumbnails/thumb.jpeg', 0777);
```